# What's a collective name for the states of Alaska and Hawaii?

Tags: single-word-requests, hypernyms

Wondering if there is a common name for the "Dis-contiguous" states of Alaska and Hawaii.
If not, what would be a good single word label to describe these two states, especially in context of dividing the country up into time zones.

Context: this is for a web application that presents data based on various filters. One of these filters is time zone.  I want to use Pacific, Mountain, Central, Eastern, and some other word that encompasses both Alaska and Hawaii, even though they are really in two different time zones.

Comment: What about "Other"?

Comment: 'Non-contiguous states of the United States'? 'Detached'? '49 and 50' (if Puerto Rico ever joins,... oh.. you care about -time zone-? This is kinda mixed up.

Comment: How about "Alaska & Hawai'i"? You'll have to update your program once a new state joins anyway.....

Comment: I agree with Mr Shiny.  I see national advertising sopmetimes with a disclaimer at the end: Prices higher in Alaska and Hawaii.  So there is no need for a fancier way to say it.

Comment: A quick note on the tags: what you are looking for is a [*hypernym*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyponymy). A [*collective noun*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collective_noun) is something entirely different.

Comment: OCONUS, you mean? [This Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contiguous_United_States#Other_terms) has some pertinent remarks about much of the discussion below, including Contiguous vs Continental U.S., and "Lower 48" as well.

Comment: You want to filter by time zone but one of the choices is actually two time zones?

Comment: Perhaps "incontinental?"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Alaska & Hawaii" is short, accurate, and precise. It's 3 words, but only 15 characters (depending on how you choose to spell Hawaii/Hawai'i/Hawaiʻi.

Comment: After seeing all the suggestions, I think I agree.  But I'm going to use AK & HI to make it even shorter. And abbreviated state names are used elsewhere in the application too.

Comment: Isn't this a single word request?

Comment: @phoenixheart6 The answer was accepted by the questioner, so I'm not sure I understand your issue.

Comment: @MarkBeadles yes, I see that. I wasn't saying that it was an issue, just stating the reason for the downvote.

Comment: @phoenixheart6 Oh, I see. The tag was not entered by the questioner.

Comment: ohh ok. It's too late for me to reverse the downvote. Sorry about that =/

Comment: There, I countered your errant downvote with an upvote even though Mitch's comment is what I consider to be the most correct given the single-word tag.

Answer (score 12):

[*Noncontinguous states*](http://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http://www.learner.org/interactives/historymap/images/fifty_pic1.gif&imgrefurl=http://www.learner.org/interactives/historymap/fifty1.html&usg=__5eNenuHARZ_n5PK5QuUk1sFD_dc=&h=226&w=418&sz=13&hl=en&start=1&zoom=1&tbnid=O2nRGiNmVD-cKM%3a&tbnh=68&tbnw=125&ei=Iy0EUMS0AsqI2gWck6icCw&prev=/images%3Fq%3Dnoncontiguous%2Bstates%26hl%3Den%26sa%3DX%26gbv%3D2%26tbm%3Disch&itbs=1) is what I've always heard those two states called.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the phrase "Non-Continental" used in many cases.

You see it most often on shipping orders where they quote prices to Continental United States

Comment: Alaska is on the continent. Is it part of the Continental US?

Comment: The US government specifies CONUS as "continental US" on [this site](http://www.gsa.gov/portal/category/100120). Alaska is specifically excluded from CONUS for governmental purposes.

Comment: Well, the EU specifies carrot as fruit and snail as "land fish". The fact some office classifies something some way doesn't make it factually correct.

Comment: @SF. Does it?  If yes, where?  Sounds weird.

Comment: @dezso: Fairly loud cases, google them. To allow fruit juices to use carrot juice, and to have snail pickers to enjoy similar protections as fishers, the regulations extended the definitions of "fruit" and "fish".

Answer (score 0):

I have heard the states other than Alaska and Hawaii called "The Lower 48".

Perhaps we could call them "The Other Two".

*[Yes, I know the standard form is to include the period inside the quotes, but the practice jars since the period is not part of what is being quoted.]*

Comment: The 48 contiguous states aren't "lower" compared to Hawaii :)

Comment: It may have taken root in those few months between the entry of Alaska and Hawaii.

Comment: In Hawaii it's usually called "the Mainland". In Alaska it's either "Lower 48" or "Outside".

Answer (score -2):

[peripheral](https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=peripheral%20definition)

/pəˈrɪf(ə)r(ə)l/

adjective

  1.

relating to or situated on the edge or periphery of something.
"the peripheral areas of Europe"

synonyms: outlying, outer, on the edge/outskirts, outermost, fringe, border, surrounding;

Comment: Alaska and Hawaii may be geographically peripheral to other states, but that isn't how anyone *classifies* them, certainly not for time zones. Besides, in terms of human geography, there's plenty of Maine or upper Michigan or Louisiana that is more peripheral than Honolulu.